# Java monitor multi threads outside the class

Tags: java, multithreading

Since I don't have the code here I'll try to be as clear as I can...

I'm developing a rest service in java that will get some params (number of threads, ammount of messages) and will create the threads (via loop) and send this number of messages via MQ (I'm passing the number of mssages when creating the thread).

So for an example if someone sends 50 threads and 5000 msgs it will send 2.5M msgs...

Now my question is how could I create another rest service to monitor all those threads and give me a % of conclusions on the messages sent.

I'm considering calling this service to update a progress bar every 2 secs via ajax.

Comment: 50 * 5000 = 250,000

Answer (score 0):

A simplified approach is to create a class to keep track of the statistics the status bar will need to display. For example:

```
public class MessageCreatorProgress {
    private final int totalMessagesToBeCreated;
    private final AtomicInteger successCount;
    private final AtomicInteger failureCount;

    // constructor to initialize values
    // increment methods
    // get methods
}
```

In the initial request which starts the threads, construct the threads with a shared instance of an `MessageCreatorProgress`.  For example:

```
// endpoint method to create a bunch of messages
public String startCreatingMessages(CreateMessagesRequest request) {
    MessageCreatorProgress progress = new MessageCreatorProgress(requesst.getThreadCount * request.getMessageCountPerThread());

   for (...) {
       new MyMessageCreator(progress, request.getSomeParameter(), ....).start();
   }

   String messageProgressId = some unique value...
   // Store MessageCreatorProgress in the session or some other shared memory,
   // so it can be accessed by subsequent calls.
   session.setAttribute(messageProgressId, progress);
   return messageProgressId;
}
```

Each `MyMessageCreator` instance would for example call `progress.incrementSuccess()` as a last step, or `progress.incrementFailure()` for an exception.

The AJAX call passes the `messageProgressId` to the status endpoint which knows how to access the `MessageCreatorProgress`:

```
// endpoint method to get the message creation progress
// transform to JSON or whatever
public MessageCreatorProgress getMessageCreationProgress(String messageProgressId) {
    return session.getAttribute(messageProgressId);
}
```

A more complex approach is to use a database - for example when the AJAX call will not hit the same server running the threads which are creating the messages. When a thread is successful or has an exception it can update a record associated with `messageProgressId`, and the AJAX endpoint checks the database and constructs a `MessageCreatorProgress` to return to the client.